# Почему свойства, которые имеют закрытые модификаторы доступа, доступны через метод?

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Возник вопрос: почему свойства, которые имеют закрытые модификаторы доступа, доступны (прошу прощения за тавтологию) через метод *printHello*?

Заранее спасибо.

```
class MyClass
{
public $public = 'Общий';
protected $protected = 'Защищенный';
private $private = 'Закрытый';

function printHello()
{
    echo $this->public;
    echo $this->protected;
    echo $this->private;
}
}

$obj = new MyClass();
echo $obj->public; // Работает
echo $obj->protected; // Неисправимая ошибка
echo $obj->private; // Неисправимая ошибка
$obj->printHello(); // Выводит Общий, Защищенный и Закрытый
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Читай меня полностью!](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php)

`public` - публичное свойство, доступно всем, в т.ч. извне.
`protected` - свойство запрещающее доступ к методу/объекту извне, но разрешает наследовать его.
`private` - доступ только у элементов класса, ни извне, ни потомки до него не могут добраться.
[Принципы инкапсулирования :)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Инкапсуляция_%28программирование%29)

В данном случае метод `printHello()` находится частью класса, поэтому он имеет доступ до всех типов свойств.
Будь он реализован в потомке - вывел бы `public` и `protected`, но заглохнет на `private`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Понял)